# Java import enumeration

Tags: java, eclipse, import, enums

Hi I had a program which worked fine in a .jar file.

Basically all the classes were part of the same package called : "eu.floraresearch.lablib.gui.checkboxtree"
They ALL are located in the SAME "checkboxTree" folder. Each file has a line stating 
    package eu.floraresearch.lablib.gui.checkboxtree;

I need to modify the code and to integrate it in another project.
So I took all the .java files, copied them in my Eclipse project folder (no package anymore), and got rid of the "package eu.floraresearch.lablib.gui.checkboxtree;" line in each files. Everything is fine except for one file comprising an enumeration.
Originally the file looked like this:

```
package eu.floraresearch.lablib.gui.checkboxtree;

public class QuadristateButtonModel extends DefaultButtonModel {

    public enum State {
        CHECKED, GREY_CHECKED, GREY_UNCHECKED, UNCHECKED
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is, there is another class which originally imported the above class enumeration:

```
import eu.floraresearch.lablib.gui.checkboxtree.QuadristateButtonModel.State;

public class QuadristateCheckbox extends JCheckBox {

    public QuadristateCheckbox() {
        this(null);
    }

    public QuadristateCheckbox(String text) {
    this(text, State.UNCHECKED);
    }
    ...
}
```

First of all I find it weird how enumerations can be imported.. But it worked fine when everything was inside the package.

Since all my .java files are in the same folder now, I just removed the package line.
However I have this issue with the QuadristateCheckbox class which imports "QuadristateButtonModel.State".

If I change the import line with

```
import QuadristateButtonModel.State;
```

it states

```
The import QuadristateButtonModel cannot be resolved
```

I tried various things I found on the internet like

```
import static QuadristateButtonModel.State.*;
```

or

```
import QuadristateButtonModel.State.*;
```

but the same error messages occur:

```
The import QuadristateButtonModel cannot be resolved
```

On top of that, in the above code from QuadristateCheckbox class:

```
public QuadristateCheckbox(String text) {
    this(text, State.UNCHECKED);
}
```

an error message

```
State cannot be resolved to a variable
```

which is understandable given the fact that I fail to import the State enumeration.

What can I do? Please explain to me what is wrong

PS: The code was taken from this site: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077762/core-java/swing-based-tree-layouts-with-checkboxtree.html

The authors provide classes to build checkable trees.

Comment: You can't import things from the default package (things that aren't in a package).

Comment: You should NEVER put classes in the default package. Precisely to avoid the problems you're having.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you.
I just moved every files into a package, it works like a charm!